# Simple php dom parser doesn't work with local url

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Does not work with this url. What is the problem?
Get error - PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
include('simple_html_2012.php');
echo file_get_html('http://www.localhost/test/test.html')->plaintext; 
?>
```

if trying to parse google.com, it all works.

Comment: `www.localhost`? With leading `www.`?

Comment: Still Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/test/index.php on line 4

Comment: 1) Is the URL valid? (i.e., can you paste it in a browser and get the site?) 2) Have you disabled `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: NetBeans tells me OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Do you mean that your IDE is crashing or that you are getting a different PHP error message depending on how you run the script. The former is quite irrelevant IMHO, the latter merits some details.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo file_get_html('http://localhost/test/test.html')->plaintext;
```

or

```
echo file_get_html('http://127.0.0.1/test/test.html')->plaintext;
```

Comment: Still Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/test/index.php on line 4

Comment: Have you tried using file_get_contents instead of file_get_html? php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

may be helpfull:

```
    if($source = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/test.html"))
    {
        $html = str_get_html($source);
        echo $html->plaintext;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Something wrong!";
    }
```

Comment: if ($html->innertext != null) {
    echo 'good';        
    } else {
    echo "bad";
    } // $html is null

Comment: NetBeans tells me OutOfMemoryError